# nav2: go exactly to this point, not approximately

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I provide a goal pose to the nav2 system on my robot, it tries it best to get within the goal tolerance of the goal, then stops. I find this behavior to be unintuitive: i should expect that the robot tries its best to get to the actual goal, then accept any result within the tolerance, but instead, it goes to the edge of the tolerance and is happy with that result. This means that if I give an xy tolerance of 1.0, it will always stop 1.0 meters from the goal. But then, if I set the xy goal tolerance too small, it oscillates around the target. Is this the intended behavior? How do I tell the nav2 system to generate a path to EXACTLY the goal, not just to any point within the tolerance? Using the pure pursuit controller if it makes a difference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413400/nav2:-go-exactly-to-this-point,-not-approximately/) by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2023-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a very reasonable potential contribution to change the behavior. However, its hard to then define when "done" is "done" without causing the exact same oscillation issues as you describe for setting very low tolerances. Basically: we would need a proposal for a metric for how to say, after we're within the tolerance, when we're completed to a satisfactory refined level.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0